# Node.js, g++ (gcc) and child process - gcc cannot open output file error

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, gcc

For programming competition, I am making simple HTML/Javascript page that takes your sources, compiles and evaluates them. This is my code for running GCC:

```
request.onfiles = function(files) {
  // Add output file name at the end of params
  files.push("-o output/main.exe");
  // Evaluate correct working path, that's /upload/username          
  var cwd = path.resolve(process.cwd(), './upload/'+request.name+"/");
  console.log(">>  "+cwd+"/g++ ", files.join(" "));
  console.log(process.cwd());
  // Run process
  var gcc = request.process = childProcess.spawn('g++',files,{env: process.env, cwd: cwd});
  gcc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
  });
  // Error output
  gcc.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
  });
  gcc.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);        
    _this.working.splice(_this.working.indexOf(request));
    _this.emit("action.compile", request.name);
    _this.tryContinue();
  });
}
```

Node.js process runs at project root and GCC is launched in `/upload/[USERNAME]/`. The `/upload/username` directory contains sourcecode:

[image: image description]

My debug output looks like this:

```
Compile by  username  requested.
>>  D:\web\soutez\upload\username/g++  main.cpp -o output\main.exe
D:\web\soutez
stderr: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin
stderr: /ld.exe: cannot open output file  output\main.exe: No such file or directory
stderr:
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

child process exited with code 1
```

If I actually copy the line with the command (`g++  main.cpp -o output\main.exe`) and go in the `upload/username`, compilation works:

[image: image description]

I also noticed that although GCC **can allways find the source**. If I add error in `main.cpp`, node.js output looks like this:

```
>>  D:\web\soutez\upload\username/g++  main.cpp -o output\main.exe
D:\web\soutez
stderr: main.cpp:2:2: error: 'XXX' does not name a type
  XXX
  ^

child process exited with code 1
```

I need some help, I don't understand what is node.js doing different. Worst thing: if I remove `/output`, it works:

```
files.push("-o main.exe");
```

[image: image description]

Comment: Are you sure the file you generate has the right permissions?

Comment: I'm on windows and I have UAC off. So everyone is admin. Also note that the error is *No such file or directory*, not *Permission denied*. I'm totally lost - first I also thought it's permissions.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. Any chance it's the backward slash causing you havoc (in output\main.exe) ?

Comment: No, I tried both forward and backvard. And even mixed slashes didn't cause any trouble with source paths.

Comment: `../main.exe: No such file or directory` doesn't work either, that's really weird. Looks like it refuses to create output in different directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `-o output/main.exe`. It should be `-ooutput/main.exe`. I found this because it worked with `-o main.exe` and after a while, I noticed there's a  (space) in the beginning of the resulting filename.